# Can't install R with PNG support

Tags: r, png, x11

I'm trying to install R with shlib and PNG support. X11, pango, and cairo are already installed on Centos 6. I used the same command to install on another machine which works fine, but not on this one machine. They're all identical. What am I doing wrong?

Here's the statement for configure.

`./configure --enable-R-shlib --with-x --with-readline --with-cairo --with-tcltk --with-libpng --with-jpeglib`

This is what I get at the end of the configuration

```
R is now configured for x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu

  Source directory:          .
  Installation directory:    /packages/R/3.1.1

  C compiler:                gcc -std=gnu99  -g -O2
  Fortran 77 compiler:       gfortran  -g -O2

  C++ compiler:              g++  -g -O2
  C++ 11 compiler:           g++  -std=c++0x -g -O2
  Fortran 90/95 compiler:    gfortran -g -O2
  Obj-C compiler:

  Interfaces supported:      X11
  External libraries:        readline
  Additional capabilities:   NLS
  Options enabled:           shared R library, shared BLAS, R profiling

  Recommended packages:      yes
```

Notice X11 is enabled. I configured with JPEG and PNG support, but it's not listed in additional capabilities.

And finally, this is what I see in R

`> capabilities()
    jpeg      png     tiff    tcltk      X11     aqua http/ftp  sockets
   FALSE    FALSE    FALSE    FALSE    FALSE    FALSE     TRUE     TRUE
  libxml     fifo   cledit    iconv      NLS  profmem    cairo
    TRUE     TRUE     TRUE     TRUE     TRUE    FALSE    FALSE`

I need a fresh set of eyes to see what I'm doing wrong. I can't seem to figure out what I'm missing.

Comment: Nevermind. I figured it out. Since it's 64 bit centos, I needed to install pango-devel.86_64 version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Must install pango... 32 or 64-bit